# Google App engine Hexadecimal decoding issue

Tags: google-app-engine, hex, decode

I have issue with decode Hex String value value to String conversion.

If Input is :

```
687474703a2f2f7777772e676f6f676c652e6c6b2f
```

Here is my decode logic:

```
private static String hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
         int len = s.length();
         byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
         for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
             data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
         }

         return new String(data);
 }
```

this one work fine with Any other java application, but For Google App engine this doesn't work.

Anyone know why this happened?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: Input and output is same. expected output is : http://www.google.lk

Answer (score 1):

App Engine's default encoding might not be what you expect.  When you construct the final String from your data byte array, pass the correct encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc).